# Singular "Search" page Rails 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to create single search resource with only new and show actions/views
[Views,Controller  and custom class in model](https://gist.github.com/DaniyarKulmanov/f159306a1e235cfca75414d66a274852)

My scenario is, in new.html.erb creating new search with populating fields.
After pressing submit button, show.html.erb shown with search result.
But in my case my @trains variable are empty in show action :(

Comment: Well... You are not setting the `@trains` variable in the `show` action?

Comment: Your `Search` class is dodgy, too - you're using a class instance variable for what should just be a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

move `@trains = Search.trains(params[:station_from], params[:station_to])`

to `show` method

Comment: Moved but same empty @trains :-(